# Como coloco um alert com IF no Javascript usando Lista de Valores

Tags: javascript, sql

Estou montando uma função javascript que faz controle de lista de valores de um **SELECT** no meu SQL. Pois a Lista de Ambos são gigantes.
Então talvez do cara clicar diretamente pra aparecer tudo da tabela, eu coloquei um **alert** no **valor2**, onde o cara é obrigado a digitar o valor. no Filtro ele trara o que o cara escreveu. e Não a lista de valor por completa.

Antes a logica era no só valor 2 essa condição, mas agora preciso colocar o alert também no valor 1, porem o meu if morre quando tento colocar o **alert** para o **valor 1** igual fiz no 2.

```
function mostra_valores(c1)
{
  var ESTILO;  
  if(typeof c1.name==="undefined"){
   ESTILO=c1.previousSibling.name;
  } else {
   ESTILO=c1.name;
  }

  if(ESTILO=="P_PARAMETER_1"){ 
    DIV_LOV.style.display="inline";
    IFRAME.location = "PACKAGE1_PKG.VALOR?P_FILTRO="+document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_1.value+"&P_TIPO=VALOR1";
     alert("Informe o valor 1");
  } else if(ESTILO=="P_PARAMETER_2"){
    if(document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_2.value.length>2){
      DIV_LOV.style.display="inline";
      IFRAME.location = "PACKAGE1_PKG.VALOR?P_FILTRO="+document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_2.value+"&P_TIPO=VALOR2";
    } else {
      alert("Informe o valor 2"); 
    }
  }
  IFRAME.focus();      
}
```

precisaria que o `alert("informe o valor 1");` fique igual a condição do `alert ("informe o valor 2");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao meu ver você poderia usar dois `if...else` separados e quando entrar num dos `else`'s, sair da função com `return;`:

```
if(ESTILO=="P_PARAMETER_1"){ 
   DIV_LOV.style.display="inline";
   IFRAME.location = "PACKAGE1_PKG.VALOR?P_FILTRO="+document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_1.value+"&P_TIPO=VALOR1";
}else{
   alert("Informe o valor 1");
   return;
}

if(ESTILO=="P_PARAMETER_2" && document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_2.value.length>2){
   DIV_LOV.style.display="inline";
   IFRAME.location = "PACKAGE1_PKG.VALOR?P_FILTRO="+document.PROCEDURE_VALOR.P_PARAMETER_2.value+"&P_TIPO=VALOR2";
} else {
   alert("Informe o valor 2"); 
   return;
}
```

Se o primeiro `if` não for satisfeito, não vai chegar no segundo. E se o primeiro `if` for satisfeito e o segundo não, não vai executar o `IFRAME.focus();`.

No segundo `if` você pode colocar as duas condições no mesmo `if`, sem ter que fazer um dentro do outro.

Comment: Nossa mais facil do que eu pensava, deu certo assim, acho que fiquei querendo enfeitar demais no IF. muito obrigado amigo